# First argument when doing onload=fn

Tags: javascript

When I do :

`img.onload=fn;`

The function fn gets the `argument[0] [object Event]`.

How can I avoid that ?

Comment: not really clear to me... where and how is defined `fn`?

Comment: `img.onload=function() { fn.call(this) };`

Comment: Why not simply ignore that argument? You're not explicitly passing an argument, so presumably you're not expecting to use one anyway. The function is passed the event which triggered it, which could be useful in some contexts. If you don't need it, don't use it.

Comment: This is why IE is the best browser *ever*.  It doesn't try to *be all cool* with this W3C compliance nonsense.  No, it puts *its* events on the window object instead. </troll>

Comment: @MikeChristensen IE passes events into the handler in the same way. The latest version of IE are a big improvement on their earlier releases, which IE10 being downright spectacular.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - I just tried on IE7 and the first argument is undefined.  What version of IE fixed this?  Not that it matters, since everyone has to support older versions of IE..

Comment: @MikeChristensen IE9+ passes the event into the arguments array. Of course supporting older versions is not difficult: `var event = event || window.event;`

Comment: @JonathanSampson - Yea, IE is definitely coming along.  Wonder if they finally use the standard `targetElement` rather than their proprietary `srcElement` now..  Course all us web devs have to wait years until the older versions of IE die off..  We're still using IE7 at my company..

Comment: @MikeChristensen Fortunately great tools like jQuery have been normalizing these APIs for some time now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't avoid event objects. You embrace them. That being said, you don't have to use it if you don't want to. When the browser fires in the `onload` event, it's passing an event object to the handler whether you request it or not. As you pointed out, this is present in the `arguments` array even when you don't specifically provide a name for it in your handler parameters.

As others here have pointed out in their answers and comments, you can add another anonymous function to further remove your response code from the event being raised, but I personally find this really unnecessary.

As @Yoshi pointed out in the comments of above, the following would work:

```
img.onload = function() { 
  fn.call(this) 
};
```

This will call your `fn` method passing in the current contextual `this` reference. Again, I personally would just avoid touching the event object instead since this type of code may confuse others and yourself six weeks from today.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jonathan Sampson answer, a simple workaround can be done like so

```
img.onload = function() {
   fn();
}
```

doing so, `arguments` is empty
see fiddle (with javascript console) : http://jsfiddle.net/ZxSEX/

Comment: Yoshi's implementation was a bit better, as it wouldn't lose the context of *this* (which may or may not be important)..

Comment: I didn't noticed his comment - @Yoshi you should write that as an answer (or you can just feel free to update mine as you prefer)

Comment: Actually I'm with Jonathan on this. So I would not want to encourage this too much.